# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python' Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have been using Tensorflow on Anaconda for a while now, but recently I have been getting the mentioned error when trying to import Tensorflow.

This has been asked here multiple times, so I tried suggested solutions but nothing worked so far (reinstalling tensorflow (both normal and gpu versions), reinstalling Anaconda). When running `help('modules')` tensorflow appears in module list. But even after I run `pip uninstall tensorflow` and `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu` tensorflow still remains in module list when running `help('modules')`.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I am using Windows 10, not sure what TS stands for

Comment: TF == Tensorflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the reason was the Python version (which is strange as according to documentation Tensorflow supports Python 3.7). I downgraded to 3.6 and I am able to import Tensorflow again

Answer (score 0):

As one of the solutions always would to manually delete TensorFlow package and then reinstall it.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/pip/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow
```

Comment: I tried manually locating and deleting tensorflow from Anaconda library folder, but for some reason TF still appears in `help('modules')`

Comment: are you using venv (virtual environment) or global modules?

Comment: Virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

Even when you uninstall tensorflow using pip, with help('modules') command, if tensorflow is still there, this might be because the packages are not accessed by python from the path "/usr/local/pip/python3.6" but rather from the path "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages".

So to uninstall tensorflow from here, try:

```
conda remove tensorflow
```

or:

```
conda remove -n your_env_name tensorflow
```

Once you do that install tensorflow using:

```
 conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Hopefully this will work.

Even if this does not work, then use rm to delete the tensorlflow package folder.

To do this do not assume that it will be present in the "/usr/local/pip/python3.6" path. But instead type:

```
pip show tensorflow
```

This will give the path from which the tensorflow module is being imported by python.

Then run:

```
rm -rf path-you-got-from-pip-show-tensorflow
```

Comment: Before doing what you had suggested I deleted anaconda and all folders associated with it. Then reinstalled, and ran `help('modules')` and some tensorflow modules were still visable (I dont think anaconda is supposed to come with TF). Then I did what you suggested, still did not work :(

Answer (score -1):

here is what helped me personally:

1. open terminal with elevated priviliges:
   in windows you can right-click on the windows symbol, open " Windows Powershell (Admin) "
2. enable long directory/path commands using command:
   New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
3. open your project/environment and open terminal/shell:

#if you already have tensorflow installed uninstall it using:

```
" pip uninstall tensorflow  " or " conda remove tensorflow   "
```

#####update pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

#####in a virtual environment or using Python 2

```
pip install tensorflow
```

#for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

#####if you get permissions error

```
sudo pip3 install tensorflow

pip install tensorflow --user
```

#####if you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable

```
python -m pip install tensorflow
```

#####for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

#####using py alias (Windows)

```
py -m pip install tensorflow
```

#####for Anaconda

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

#####for Jupyter Notebook

```
!pip install tensorflow
```

## source:

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-tensorflow