# No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package

Tags: python, tensorflow

Everything was working smoothly until I started getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/user/Workspace/Practices/Tensorflow/tensorflow2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 98, in 
>       from tensorflow_core import *
>     File "/home/user/Workspace/Practices/Tensorflow/tensorflow2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/**init**.py", line 40, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _modle_util
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package

My environment setup:

- python-3.7
- Using venv module to create virtual environment
  tensorflow 2.0.0
- pip 19.0.3
- Manjaro Linux

Now, I even can't import tensorflow module as well. It gives same above error. Tried reinstalling with cache and without cache as well, but no luck. Recreated virtual environment as well, no luck. This is really weird and have no clue where to start troubleshooting as well. Looking at virtual environment site packages, everything seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this problem right now. I ran the source code on another computer and it showed the same error. I went ahead and compared the version of TensorFlow and turns out that the other computer was running tensorflow==2.1.0 and mine was running tensorflow==1.14.0.

> In short, downgrade your tensorflow installation (pip install tensorflow==1.14.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling. First run:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

then reinstall:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

After you uninstall, in the python shell, run:

```
help('modules')
```

TensorFlow should not be there in that list. Only then proceed to install it.

Comment: If you see tensorflow in help('modules') even after you uninstall it, then refer this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/59116667/11517841

Comment: Hey @Sushanth, thanks for your effort man... I have been doing uninstalling then reinstalling with cache and without cache lots of time man... But no luck... If I uninstalled tensorflow and look at modules, then tensorflow is not shown, except tensorflow board and estimator. If installed and look at modules, all of the tensorflow modules are shown. There's no conda environment in my PC as well.

Comment: Hey @Sushanth, found an interesting behavior. I deleted my virtual environment. Created new one and activated it. Installed tensorflow 2. Went to python interpreter/console. And the import works. After that, I exited python console. Create a python file with just import and print statement. Ran a file then same above error occurred. Went to console again and imported tensorflow. Now I was not even able to import tensorflow in console which was working previously. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Found a noob problem. I was using my file name as csv.py which already exist in python library, which I think was messing up the paths. But don't know how yet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall tensorflow what version you have because it will take time to reinstall. You can fix this issue just by installing tensorflow==2.0.

`pip install tensorflow==2.0`

Answer (score 0):

here is what helped me personally:

1. open terminal with elevated priviliges:
   in windows you can right-click on the windows symbol, open " Windows Powershell (Admin) "
2. enable long directory/path commands:
   New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
3. open your project/environment and open terminal/shell:

(if you already have tensorflow installed uninstall it using " pip uninstall tensorflow  " or " conda remove tensorflow   " )

## update pip

pip install --upgrade pip

## in a virtual environment or using Python 2

pip install tensorflow

## for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)

pip3 install tensorflow

## if you get permissions error

sudo pip3 install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow --user

## if you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable

python -m pip install tensorflow

## for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)

python3 -m pip install tensorflow

## using py alias (Windows)

py -m pip install tensorflow

## for Anaconda

conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

## for Jupyter Notebook

!pip install tensorflow

source: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-tensorflow